# How do I declare multiple if statements on one line based on user input?

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
if (userInput == "hello") ***or*** (userInput == "bye")
{
    Console.WriteLine("So, which one is it?");
}
```

In context, I would like the user to input two decisions meaning the same thing using two if statements on one line.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of accomplishing this. Perhaps the simplest one would be using `||` operator:

```
if (userInput == "hello" || userInput == "bye")
{
    Console.WriteLine("So, which one is it?");
}
```

If the list is longer, you could create a list, and look for a match like this:

```
var responses = new List<string> {
    "hello", "bye"
};
if (responses.Contains(userInput)) {
    Console.WriteLine("So, which one is it?");
}
```

Yet another solution is using `switch` statement:

```
switch (userInput) {
    case "hello":
    case "bye":
        ...
        break;
    case "go-away":
    case "come-back":
        ...
        break;
}
```

Comment: it not a very good idea for the second option, because it too long and does not work in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

That's simple:

```
if (userInput == "hello" || userInput == "bye") // This line had changed
{
    Console.WriteLine("So, which one is it?");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this for OR:

```
if (userInput == "hello" || userInput == "bye")
{
    Console.WriteLine("So, which one is it?");
}
```

Or this if you want BOTH of the true

```
if (userInput == "hello" && userInput == "bye")
{
    Console.WriteLine("So, which one is it?");
}
```